# Get output logs of previous command in ZSH

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, zsh

I'm working on a helper script that needs to run after every command to analyze its exit status and output logs.

I understand that stdout/stderr buffers are not stored on pseudo terminals. I therefore looked for a way to "save" this output to a temporary file before every command then read it after.

Here's what I added to my `.zshrc`:

```bash
LAST_OUTPUT_LOG_FILE="$HOME/zero.log"
exec 3>&1 1> >(tee $LAST_OUTPUT_LOG_FILE >&3)
# based on https://superuser.com/a/1111512/1748711
echo "Using $LAST_OUTPUT_LOG_FILE"

precmd () {
    LAST_STATUS=$?
    LAST_COMMAND=$(fc -ln -1)
    echo "Last command: $LAST_COMMAND exited with status $LAST_STATUS"
    echo "--------------- LAST COMMAND LOG $LAST_OUTPUT_LOG_FILE ---------------"
    cat $LAST_OUTPUT_LOG_FILE
    echo "--------------- LAST COMMAND LOG $LAST_OUTPUT_LOG_FILE ---------------"
    # run my script here with the last command, its status and its output

    # reset the log file
    echo "" > $LAST_OUTPUT_LOG_FILE
}
```

Except when i load a new terminal and enter a command (say `ls`) I get the following error:

```
precmd:echo:3: write error: broken pipe
precmd:3: write error: broken pipe
precmd:echo:4: write error: broken pipe
precmd:4: write error: broken pipe
precmd:echo:6: write error: broken pipe
precmd:6: write error: broken pipe
```

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible? And if so what am I missing here?

Cheers!

Comment: Why is this question tagged `zsh` *and* `bash`? Do you want your script to work in both these shells?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski ideally yes

Answer (score 0):

#### What am I missing here?

Checking your code with [ShellCheck – shell script analysis tool](https://www.shellcheck.net/):

```
$ shellcheck myscript
 
Line 2:
LAST_OUTPUT_LOG_FILE="~/zero.log"
                      ^-- SC2088 (warning): Tilde does not expand in quotes. Use $HOME.
```

Trying fixing that.

Comment: Nice catch! I've replaced it with $HOME. The `no such file or directory: ~/zero.log` error is gone, but the `broken pipe` one persists :/